# separate a list in parentheses keeping them inside a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

and i want this:

```
x = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6)]
```

I am interested in knowing if there is a library that performs this procedure directly. otherwise, how to do it with some function

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Yes - there are many ways to achieve this easily with builtin functions - the 2 common ways to achieve this  use either `zip` and `iter`; or  `range` and  list `slices`. Come back once you have tried some approaches

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Answer (score 1):

Out of many ways, you can use python listcomp here.

```
[(x[i], x[i+1]) for i in range(len(x) - 1)]
```

P.S.: Stackoverflow is not for these type of questions. Please try atleast some way before asking question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
def f(x):
    res: list[tuple] = []
    for i in range(len(x)-1):
        res.append((x[i], x[i+1]))
    return res
```

test:

```
In [5]: def f(x):
   ...:     res: list[tuple] = []
   ...:     for i in range(len(x)-1):
   ...:         res.append((x[i], x[i+1]))
   ...:     return res
   ...: 

In [6]:  x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

In [7]: f(x)
Out[7]: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)]
```